# A very simple Calculator with data validation

Tags: java, validation

I'm trying to make a simple calculator but I can't seem to figure out how to make a data validation.

The kind of data validation I'm trying to make is:

1. Error message appear when there's no input on the textfield.
2. Error message appear when you put alphabets or any character other
   than numbers.

Here's a whole of my code. Please help me.

```
/*
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
package my.calculator;

/**
 *
 * @author Admin
 */
public class CalculatorUI extends javax.swing.JFrame {

    /**
     * Creates new form CalculatorUI
     */
    public CalculatorUI() {
        initComponents();
    }

    /**
     * This method is called from within the constructor to initialize the form.
     * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is always
     * regenerated by the Form Editor.
     */
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jTextField1 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jTextField3 = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton2 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton3 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton4 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton5 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jButton6 = new javax.swing.JButton();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel1.setBorder(new javax.swing.border.MatteBorder(null));

        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 2, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel1.setText("First number :");

        jLabel2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel2.setText("Second number :");

        jLabel3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 11)); // NOI18N
        jLabel3.setText("Answer :");

        jTextField1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 255));
        jTextField1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 11)); // NOI18N

        jTextField2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 255));
        jTextField2.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 11)); // NOI18N

        jTextField3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(204, 255, 255));
        jTextField3.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Times New Roman", 0, 11)); // NOI18N

        jButton1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 51, 0));
        jButton1.setText("+");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton2.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jButton2.setText("-");
        jButton2.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton2ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jButton3.setText("*");
        jButton3.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton3ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton4.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jButton4.setText("/");
        jButton4.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton4ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton5.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(255, 0, 0));
        jButton5.setText("%");
        jButton5.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton5ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        jButton6.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 255, 0));
        jButton6.setText("Exit");
        jButton6.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton6ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(43, 43, 43)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING)
                    .addComponent(jLabel2)
                    .addComponent(jLabel3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 50, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jTextField2)
                    .addComponent(jTextField3))
                .addGap(33, 33, 33)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addGap(18, 18, 18)
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING, false)
                    .addComponent(jButton5, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                    .addComponent(jButton4, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE))
                .addContainerGap(53, Short.MAX_VALUE))
            .addGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap(javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton6)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(17, 17, 17)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel1)
                            .addComponent(jButton1)
                            .addComponent(jTextField1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 27, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE))
                        .addGap(9, 9, 9)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                                .addComponent(jLabel2)
                                .addComponent(jButton2))
                            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                                .addGap(1, 1, 1)
                                .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 26, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)))
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.BASELINE)
                            .addComponent(jLabel3)
                            .addComponent(jTextField3, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 23, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                            .addComponent(jButton3)))
                    .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                        .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                        .addComponent(jButton4)
                        .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
                        .addComponent(jButton5)))
                .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.RELATED, 79, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addComponent(jButton6)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addContainerGap()
                .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
                .addContainerGap())
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>                        

    private void jButton6ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        System.exit (0);
    }                                        

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        float num1, num2, answer;
        num1 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
        answer = num1+num2;
        jTextField3.setText (String.valueOf(answer));
    }                                        

    private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        float num1, num2, answer;
        num1 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
        answer = num1-num2;
        jTextField3.setText (String.valueOf(answer));
    }                                        

    private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        float num1, num2, answer;
        num1 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
        answer = num1*num2;
        jTextField3.setText (String.valueOf(answer));
    }                                        

    private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        float num1, num2, answer;
        num1 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
        answer = num1/num2;
        jTextField3.setText (String.valueOf(answer));
    }                                        

    private void jButton5ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
        float num1, num2, answer;
        num2 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField2.getText());
        num1 = Float.parseFloat(jTextField1.getText());
        answer = (num1/num2)*100;
        jTextField3.setText (String.valueOf(answer));
    }                                        

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
         * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
         */
        try {
            for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
                if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
                    javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
                    break;
                }
            }
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalculatorUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalculatorUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalculatorUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(CalculatorUI.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
        //</editor-fold>

        /* Create and display the form */
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                new CalculatorUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton2;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton3;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton4;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton5;
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton6;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField1;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField2;
    private javax.swing.JTextField jTextField3;
    // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: ***please please please*** use proper naming conventions in your code.

Comment: **NOT** using names like 'jTextField3' or 'jButton3' as these mean *nothing*. Give meaningful names to every button/control you make.

Comment: That is a lot of code for us to read. Is all of it required to understand your problem?

Comment: I think he means instead of saying "private javax.swing.JButton jButton1", just import them instead using "import javax.swing.*" and declare the variables using "private JButton jButton1"

Answer (score 0):

You could use String's [matches](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#matches%28java.lang.String%29) method with a regex like below to resolve both kind of your validation requirements:

```
if (!textFieldValue.matches("[0-9]+")) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Hey Your textbox value contains illegal value " + textFieldValue);
}
```

Comment: Where should i put that?

Comment: You could put this validation in your action performed method just before doing actual calculations.